# Why is 'or' operation altering behavior than two separate calls for conditions?

Tags: python, matrix

I have this input matrix and I am trying to produce this output matrix.

input = [[1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

output = [[1,0,1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]

when I call the function below, I get a row of zeros as expected:

output = [[1,1,1], [0,0,0], [1,1,1]]

```
def setZero(matrix):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0):
                row = i
                col = j
                rowCol(matrix, row, col)
    return matrix 

def rowCol(matrix, row, col):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
            if i == row:
                matrix[i][j] = 0

print(setZero(matrix))
```

when I call the function below, I get a column of zeros as expected:

output = [[1,0,1], [1,0,1], [1,0,1]]

```
def setZero(matrix):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0):
                row = i
                col = j
                rowCol(matrix, row, col)
    return matrix 

def rowCol(matrix, row, col):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
            if j == col:
                matrix[i][j] = 0

print(setZero(matrix))
```

However when I combine both: 
`if i == row or j == col:`
I get the output below:

output = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

instead of output = [[1,0,1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]

```
def setZero(matrix):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0):
                row = i
                col = j
                rowCol(matrix, row, col)
    return matrix 

def rowCol(matrix, row, col):
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
            if i == row or j == col:
                matrix[i][j] = 0

print(setZero(matrix))
```

Why is this happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying your matrix in place, which means that the `if (matrix[i][j] == 0)` test in `setZero` sees the values that have been modified by `rowCol`. When you're only working in one dimension, you get the result you wanted pretty much by accident — you're doing some extra `rowCol` calls but they only end up zeroing out things that were already zeroed, so the problem is invisible. But with the `i == row or j == col` test, it's catastrophic.

First you encounter the zero at `[1][1]` and zero out row 1 and column 1.
Then you encounter the zero you just created at `[1][2]`, which zeroes out column 2.
Then you encounter the zero you created at `[2][1]`, which zeroes out row 2.

So what you created is a function that zeroes out everything in the same row as an input zero, everything in the same column as an input zero, *and* everything that lies down or right from an input zero.

What you need to do is to make a copy of `matrix` before you loop over it, and then you can keep modifying your ouptut, but you only zero a row or column if the value is zero in the *unmodified copy* of the input.